# Query create table as with inner join select and group by (ORACLE)

Tags: oracle, group-by, inner-join, create-table

This is my query, if i run the error is : Error in query: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis, anybody can solve my problem?

```
Create table r_tcash_loci_act_tmp AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
R_TCASH_LOCI_ACT.MSISDN AS MSISDN_LOCI,
R_TCASH_ACT_MSISDN.MSISDN AS MSISDN_ACT,
R_TCASH_LOCI_ACT.AREA,
R_TCASH_LOCI_ACT.REGIONAL,
R_TCASH_LOCI_ACT.BRANCH,
R_TCASH_LOCI_ACT.SUB_BRANCH,
R_TCASH_LOCI_ACT.CLUSTERX,
R_TCASH_LOCI_ACT.UPDATED,
R_TCASH_ACT_MSISDN.DAILY,
R_TCASH_ACT_MSISDN.TOTAL_TRX,
R_TCASH_ACT_MSISDN.TOTAL_VOL
FROM R_TCASH_ACT_MSISDN
INNER JOIN R_TCASH_LOCI_ACT
ON R_TCASH_LOCI_ACT.MSISDN = R_TCASH_ACT_MSISDN.MSISDN
GROUP BY R_TCASH_LOCI_ACT.MSISDN AS MSISDN_LOCI
HAVING COUNT(R_TCASH_LOCI_ACT.MSISDN ) > 10);
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle foreign tables?

Comment: i have 2 tables, and i make table temp from the 2 table, but i want to group by and having count the 2 tables, cmiiw.

Comment: Are you using Oracle foreign tables?

Comment: no i'm not using  Oracle foreign tables

Comment: Since your tag says you are using PostgreSQL, not Oracle, how can you get an ORA-00907 error?

Comment: i'm sorry , i have changed

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple syntax error. You included the column alias in the `GROUP BY`clause (probably a cut'n'paste error).

```
GROUP BY R_TCASH_LOCI_ACT.MSISDN AS MSISDN_LOCI
```

So just remove the `AS MSISDN_LOCI`.

Although given that you have a `DISTINCT` clause and no aggregated columns it's a mystery why you have the `GROUP BY` at all. You should remove the whole line.